# How to add id tag in form_for in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add an id tag to a form_for tag is below:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
```

And is it possible for me to add an id to the form_for embedded ruby, or do I have to create a form_tag field and add the id there? If I have to create a form_tag field, how do I add the id and create the form_tag field properly?
Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path,:html => {:id => "your id"}) do |f| %>
```

You can do with `form_tag` also

```
<%= form_tag(:session, url:sessions_path, id:'your id') do |f| %>
```